# MSSQL Trigger for update is working only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-trigger

I'm going to create a trigger for update. Purpose of this trigger is that If **muadurum** column is changed , take the old value of **mua_tarih** in table fkayitlar and insert to another table **mua_tarihleri**.

My code block like;

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgr_fkayit_update]
ON [dbo].[fkayitlar]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @mua_durum_once NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @mua_durum_sonra NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @mua_tarih_once DATE
DECLARE @mua_yapan_once NVARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @kisi_id INT
```

Take the old value;

```
SELECT
@kisi_id=kayitid,
@mua_durum_once=muayenedurum,
@mua_tarih_once=muayenetarih,
@mua_yapan_once=mua_yapan 
FROM deleted
```

Take the new value;

```
SELECT @mua_durum_sonra=muayenedurum FROM inserted
```

Check if value is changed ; if changed, Insert @mua_tarih to table **mua_tarihleri** with **@kisi_id** and **@mua_yapan_once**

```
  IF @mua_durum_once='OLDU' 
  AND @mua_durum_sonra='OLMADI' 
   AND @mua_tarih_once IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mua_tarihleri(kayitid,mua_tarihi,mua_yapan) 
        VALUES(@kisi_id,@mua_tarih_once,@mua_yapan_once)
     END
```

My problem is When I update more than one row in table fkayitlar,Trigger is working, but I see only one inserted row in table **mua_tarihleri** (only working once). I need to see more than one.(should be working more than once) **Are not Triggers  working on more than one process?** or **How can I solve this my problem?**

Comment: The trigger only occurs once when the table is updated, no matter how many rows are updated. Therefore, you have to write your trigger body to operate on a set of rows, not a single row as you have done.

Comment: `deleted` is a virtual table, i.e. can contain multiple rows. A single delete statement deleting three rows, will cause the `deleted` table in a trigger to have three rows. Take this into account and you should be good.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ **UPDATE fkayitlar SET muayenedurum='OLMADI',muayenetarih=NULL WHERE GETDATE()>periyodiktarih** When i run this query, more than one row is effected and all of them must be insterted to table **mua_tarihleri** but it can't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger only occurs once when the table is updated, no matter how many rows are updated. Therefore, you have to write your trigger body to operate on a set of rows, not a single row as you have done.

Should be something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgr_fkayit_update]
ON [dbo].[fkayitlar]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO mua_tarihleri(kayitid,mua_tarihi,mua_yapan) 
    SELECT deleted.kayitid, deleted.muayenedurum, deleted.muayenetarih, deleted.mua_yapan 
    FROM deleted
    JOIN inserted ON deleted.kayitid = inserted.kayitid
    WHERE deleted.muayenedurum='OLDU'
        AND inserted.muayenedurum='OLMADI'
        AND muayenetarih IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) it's working now. I appreciated.